# DFSR fails before initialization. Event ID: 4010, 3006, 2010, 4004

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, dfs, dfs-r

I have a 2 server DFSR configuration where I am attempting to replicate two shares between them. ServerA (2008R2) is the primary and ServerB(2012R2) is the receiver, both are DCs. The RepFolder on ServerA was previously configured in a replication scheme that was removed quite awhile back. I was able to get one share replicating after the following:

1. Deleting the replication group
2. Synchonizing with repadmin /syncall /AeD and ensuring all records are clear with ADSIedit
3. Running DFSRdiag pollad on ServerA and ServerB
4. Deleting dfsrprivate from the replicated folders
5. Rebuilding the replication group with a different name
6. repadmin /syncall /AeD
7. DFSRdiag pollad on ServerA and ServerB

Unfortunately the other share will not start replication and any combination of new folder, deletion, or renaming fails with the following DFSR events IDs like clockwork:

ServerA:

1. 4010: The DFS Replication service detected that the replicated folder at local path D:\ServerA\RepFolder has been removed from configuration.
2. 3006: The DFS Replication service has detected that replication group RepGroup was removed from the configuration.
3. 2010: The DFS Replication service has detected that all replicated folders on volume D: have been disabled or deleted.
4. 4004: The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the replicated folder at local path D:\ServerA\RepFolder. Additional Information: Error: 9003 (The replication group is invalid)

ServerB:

1. 2010: The DFS Replication service has detected that all replicated folders on volume E: have been disabled or deleted.
2. 4004: The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the replicated folder at local path E:\ServerB\RepFolder.
3. 2002: The DFS Replication service successfully initialized replication on volume E:.
4. 4002: The DFS Replication service successfully initialized the replicated folder at local path E:\ServerB\RepFolder.
5. 4102: The DFS Replication service initialized the replicated folder at local path E:\ServerB\RepFolder and is waiting to perform initial replication. The replicated folder will remain in this state until it has received replicated data, directly or indirectly, from the designated primary member.

ServerA will continue to retry every so often and throw identical event id 4004 as above.

Health report: [HTML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4lk4pdej2yaefv/Health-ServerA-28Apr2015-0825.html?dl=0) [XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhjl3q7qf09ollb/Health-ServerA-28Apr2015-0825.xml?dl=0)

With I've attached a link to download the Health Report. Names have been changed to protect the innocent, so apologies for any mistakes within it. Assistance is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *link leads to a .zip file* ...uh, nope. Not touching that.

Comment: Were these servers provisioned from the same image/template without being sysprepped? Do the disks in question share the same VolumeID?

Comment: Nathan, I understand your skepticism, apologies.

html: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4lk4pdej2yaefv/Health-ServerA-28Apr2015-0825.html?dl=0
xml: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhjl3q7qf09ollb/Health-ServerA-28Apr2015-0825.xml?dl=0

Comment: The volume IDs are unique. The servers are 2008R2 and 20012R2 respectively.

Comment: Anyone out there have any ideas?